# How to set that php? If statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

I have a php question and cant figure it out as Im not a coder but understand a llllittle ;)

So I have this two codes:

```
   $mod_list .= '<p class="proCalBand" style="background:'.$row["act_format"].'";><a target="_blank" href="'.$page_url.'">'.$row["name"].'</a></p>'; //.$page_url.}
```

and

```
$mod_list .= '<p class="proCalBand" style="background:'.$row["act_format"].'";><a target="_blank" href="'.$page_url.'"><img src="'.$row["custom4"].'" class="slikca" /></a><a target="_blank" href="'.$page_url.'"><b>'.$row["name"].'</a></p>'; //.$page_url.}
```

I want them to work like this.
If nothing is changed it is always the first one.
But if I set the (custom4) "in my CMS" then it shows the second one and not the first one. (custom4) is an image field set in my CMS.

```
<img src="'.$row["custom4"].'" class="slikca" />
```

this is the only change in betwen the codes.`

it is a droplet for an event calendar. That some of events will have images and some will not. Now it works, if I just put the second code in and delete the first one, but then it stil preserve class="slikca" from it, I dont want that.

Hope u understand

Thank you
R.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($row['custom4'])) {
    // custom4 exists
    $mod_list .= '<p class="proCalBand" style="background:'.$row["act_format"].'";><a target="_blank" href="'.$page_url.'"><img src="'.$row["custom4"].'" class="slikca" /></a><a target="_blank" href="'.$page_url.'"><b>'.$row["name"].'</a></p>'; //.$page_url.}
} else {
    // custom4 doesn't exist
    $mod_list .= '<p class="proCalBand" style="background:'.$row["act_format"].'";><a target="_blank" href="'.$page_url.'">'.$row["name"].'</a></p>'; //.$page_url.}
}
```

Comment: This will throw an `undefined index` notice if `custom4` doesn't exists. `if(isset($row['custom4'])) {` is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Actually, if `$row` is the result of a database lookup, and `custom4` is always a selected column, `$row['custom4']` *will* always be set.

Comment: @George - in that case, just to be sure, you can do something like `if(isset($row['custom4']) && strlen($row['custom4'] > 0)) {`

Comment: `if(isset($row['custom4']) && $row['custom4'])` would do just fine since, as mentioned, we are expecting a file path.

Comment: Yes, you guys rock It's working perfect now, just need to stile it a little and it will be perfect. I used George suggestion!